# Connect two PCs via Ethernet to multiply bandwidth of 1 Gbps NIC

Tags: networking, lan, ethernet

I just wanted to know if there is a way to create an Ethernet channel between two PCs.

Let's say that I have two PCs each having two 1 Gbps NICs, then I want to connect them together so that there is just one LAN connection on each with its specific IP address but with 2Gbps bandwidth.

This is what is used to increase the connection speed between two Cisco switches.

Comment: Yes, you can create an aggregate connection, but usually it requires that the switch also has this capability. What operating system are you using and what is the model of your switch?

Comment: Is it possible: **Yes** it is.  One has to consider the fact everything else about both machines would limit the 2Gbps performance by a good amount.  Doing this WILL NOT double your actual bandwidth just the bandwidth in theory that will be possible ( which is pretty much useless ).  The CISCO switches will still be limited to a single 1 Gbps port though.

Comment: let's say that I have no switch and just want to create a point to point connection between two PCs.. using straight cables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got some helpful tips about link aggregation on UBUNTU here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding
it works with every NIC

but for windows I got this : "windows doesn't generally support link aggregation but some specific NICs support NIC teaming on windows with their special softwares"

Comment: NIC teaming is up to the NIC drivers in Windows.  HP and Intel PRO NICs (and most probably others) have drivers which support teaming.  Windows Server 8 will support teaming natively.

Comment: "Windows Server 8 will support teaming natively" any links would be appreciated

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=windows+server+8+NIC+teaming&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-gb:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&redir_esc=&ei=a0O7T7STFJOD8gOG17DGCg - knock yourself out.

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to make sure that your switches support link aggregation, 802.ad.

Secondly, you will need to bond your NICs in a team. I've worked with intel adapters in the past to do this. Check out my blog on details of that.

http://wordpress.vaas.me/?p=25

Also, on the managed switch, you'll need to bond the two physical ports.

Comment: good but lets make it more general ... I didn't see this teaming option in my Gigabyte NIC...

Comment: What about if one doesn't have a managed switch?